# Get usable work area with ctypes

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes, user32

my goal is to get the usable work area in python with help of ctypes and the user32.dll ([SystemParametersInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx)). Well, I'm using ctypes for the second time and don't understand it a lot. An explanation what I did wrong would be great. Thanks.

```
import ctypes

SPI_GETWORKAREA = 48
SPI = ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA

class RECT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('left', ctypes.c_long),
        ('top', ctypes.c_long),
        ('right', ctypes.c_long),
        ('bottom', ctypes.c_long)
    ]

SPI.restype = ctypes.POINTER(RECT)
SPI.argtypes = [ctypes.c_uint, ctypes.c_uint, ctypes.c_uint]
result = SPI(SPI_GETWORKAREA, 0, 0)
print(result)
```

Comment: How does it fail? Any error messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few errors:

- Python 3 uses unicode strings so use `SystemParametersInfoW` instead (although it might work either way for this specific function).
- The function call is expecting 4 arguments, not 3.
- The return type is a boolean, not the rectangle structure.
- You'll need to access the same `RECT` structure you passed in after the function call. The function call modifies it in place.

Incorporating those changes the code works for me:

```
import ctypes


SPI_GETWORKAREA = 48
SPI = ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW


class RECT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('left', ctypes.c_long),
        ('top', ctypes.c_long),
        ('right', ctypes.c_long),
        ('bottom', ctypes.c_long)
    ]


SPI.restype = ctypes.c_bool
SPI.argtypes = [
    ctypes.c_uint,
    ctypes.c_uint,
    ctypes.POINTER(RECT),
    ctypes.c_uint
]

rect = RECT()

result = SPI(
    SPI_GETWORKAREA,
    0, 
    ctypes.byref(rect),
    0
)
if result:
    print('it worked!')
    print(rect.left)
    print(rect.top)
    print(rect.right)
    print(rect.bottom)
```

Comment: To simplify even more, use `from ctypes import wintypes` and the already defined `wintypes.RECT` and `wintypes.PRECT`.